# gridview column - only display first 20 characters of field

Tags: sql, t-sql, gridview

I have a gridview and when populated the length of the returned field is greater than the column width making things look a bit messy. How can I display only say the first 20 characters in the column or of the field returned.

If I can't do it in Gridview then how can I tell the sql select statement to return only a certain amount of characters?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using SQL 2005 then

You can use Left function

```
       SELECT LEFT('ColumnName', 20)
```

Also can find many such useful functions [here](http://sqltutorials.blogspot.com/2007/06/sql-string-functions.html)

Comment: yeah I'm using this..it works better with 'as' select left('columnname',20) as title

Answer (score 1):

I've used this type of technique before to display an ellipsis on truncated text

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Len(col) > 20 THEN LEFT(col, 19) + N'…'
         ELSE col
       END AS col
FROM   t
```